# How to show menu Items depends upon the condition using reactjs

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

Hi My objective is to show different menu Item based on the condition. I could retrieve different Menuitem based on condition but could not able to click or handleChange is also not working.

Here is the code:

```
<FormControl>
  <Select
    defaultValue=""
    onChange={this.handleChange}
    displayEmpty
    name="games"
    inputProps={{ "aria-label": "Without label" }}
  >
    <MenuItem value="">Game Type* </MenuItem>
    {this.state.indoor === true ? (
      <>
        <MenuItem value={0}>Carrom</MenuItem>
        <MenuItem value={1}>Chess</MenuItem>
        <MenuItem value={2}>Ludo</MenuItem>
      </>
    ) : (
      <MenuItem value={0}>Badminton</MenuItem>
    )}
  </Select>
</FormControl>

handleChange = (e) => {
    this.setState({gameName: e.target.value})
}
```

Can anyone please help me in getting clicked the list of menuItems? I could not able to click on any of the menuItem. It just giving the value of the `Carrom`  when i console it. Is that because of the `<> </>`which i provided? before i write condition, it is working fine. But after writing condition onChange is not working and click also not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A possible soultion would be to define the `games` before we render the options.

```js
...

const games = indoor === true ? ["Carrom", "Chess", "Ludo"] : ["Badminton"];

return (
  <FormControl>
    <Select
      defaultValue=""
      onChange={handleChange}
      displayEmpty
      name="games"
      inputProps={{ "aria-label": "Without label" }}
    >
      <MenuItem value="">Game Type* </MenuItem>
      {games.map((game, i) => (
        <MenuItem value={i}>{game}</MenuItem>
      ))}
    </Select>
  </FormControl>
);
```

[image: Edit billowing-meadow-7q87q]